# Rails Simple_form gem and jQuery Mobile Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using the simple_form gem in rails 3.2.2 and am trying to set up checboxes for a HABTM association.

A **Monitoring** has and belongs to many **Scenarios** and vica versa.

Using simple form, I can output a set of checkboxes automatically using:

```
= f.association :scenarios, as: :check_boxes
```

This produces the following output:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <div class="ui-checkbox">
      <input class="check_boxes optional" id="monitoring_scenario_ids_1" name="monitoring[scenario_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      </div>
    Haraam Meat Found</label>
  <input name="monitoring[scenario_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

However, jQuery Mobile will only style and recognise it if it is in the following format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-0" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-0">I agree</label>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `config.boolean_style` from `:nested` to `:inline` in your config/initializers/simple_form.rb as you can see in these line https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb.tt#L94-98

Comment: This works, but doesn't render it as a grouped checkbox. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: All the collection_check_boxes are rendered as inline. Is it not occurring?

Comment: It's now rendering them as valid jQuery Mobile checkboxes. However, the checkboxes aren't grouped.
You can see what I mean on the [docs page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/), What I'm getting is the first example, and what I'm looking for is the vertically grouped checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but you can re-organize your HTML when the `pagecreate` event fires:

```
//wait for the page to be created
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function () {

    //loop through each of the `div.checkbox` elements
    $.each($(this).find('div.checkbox'), function (index, element) {

        //cache the label for this `div.checkbox` element and the form inputs
        var $label = $(this).children('label').attr('for', $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].id),
            $inputs = $label.find('input');

        //append the inputs at the same level as the label,
        //then select the checkbox and initialize a checkbox widget
        $label.parent().append($inputs).children('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio();
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vAjDn/2/